# Problem with React Router when deploy build on Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router-dom

I've done some routing for my ReactJS application, it work perfectly in localhost. But when i want to deploy it on my Node.js server, i can only access to my root path '/'. For the other i get this:

```
Cannot GET /dir/secret/dashboard
```

I'm pretty sure that i've done something wrong but i can't figure out what.

Here's the code where i use react-route-dom:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';

import App from './App';

import Register from './pages/Register';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import Settings from './pages/Settings';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
            <Route path='/dir/secret/login' component={Login} />
            <Route path="/dir/secret/register" component={Register} />  
            <Route exact path="/dir/secret/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/dir/secret/dashboard/settings" component={Settings} />      
        </div>
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const cron = require('node-cron');
const axios = require('axios');

const port = 4200;
const cors = require('cors');

mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://***:***@***-hsm29.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('> Connected to your MongoDB Cluster');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('App starting error:', err.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    });

const router = require('./routes/router');

const corsOption = {
    origin: '*',
    optionSuccessStatus: 200,
}

server.use(express.static('public'));
server.use(cors(corsOption));
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
server.use(bodyParser.json());

const upload = require('./upload')
server.post('/upload', upload)

const banner = require('./banner')
server.post('/banner', banner)

server.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

server.use('/api', router);

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
-server.get('/', function (req, res) {
+server.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 });
});

server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Thank's by advance for your time and your help

Comment: Your Express settings are a little confusing - are you expecting the React code to be in `./build`, or `./public`? Also you seem to have posted a *diff*.

Comment: I've put my React build in the build folder of my server. The public directory is for the media files. What do you mean by 'a diff' ? I'm new on stackoverflow, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i've fixed my problem. Here's the modifications i've made

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';

import App from './App';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Content from './pages/Content';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import Settings from './pages/Settings';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+'/'}>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Content}/>
            <Route path='/dir/secret/login' component={Login} />
            <Route path="/dir/secret/register" component={Register} />  
            <Route exact path="/dir/secret/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/dir/secret/dashboard/settings" component={Settings} />      
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const cron = require('node-cron');
const axios = require('axios');

const port = 4200;
const cors = require('cors');

mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://***:***@***-hsm29.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('> Connected to your MongoDB Cluster');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('App starting error:', err.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    });

const router = require('./routes/router');

const corsOption = {
    origin: '*',
    optionSuccessStatus: 200,
}

server.use(express.static('public'));
server.use(cors(corsOption));
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
server.use(bodyParser.json());

const upload = require('./upload')
server.post('/upload', upload)

const banner = require('./banner')
server.post('/banner', banner)

server.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

server.use('/api', router);

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
server.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

So i've modify all my routing to match the react-router-dom documentation and i just change this :

```
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
-server.get('/', function (req, res) {
+server.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 });
```

to this :

```
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
server.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

i'm pretty sure that there is a better way to do what i want but the fact is that this way work for me so if it could help anyone.